# Program only uses one shader, whereas I am trying to connect 2 shaders

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, shader

I am using OpenGl with Java and currenctly I am trying to connect 2 different shader programs (one for each object I wish to render) with my code. Despite that, at the end only one shader connects efficietly and I think (not sure though) that it overrides the first one. My code is pretty long so I am not sure how much information I should provide, so lets me know if I should post the code of my shaders as well:

```
public class Aufgabe3undFolgende extends AbstractOpenGLBase {

private ShaderProgram shaderProgram;
private ShaderProgram shaderProgram2;


private Matrix4 matrix = new Matrix4();
private Matrix4 secondMatrix = new Matrix4();
private Matrix4 projection = new Matrix4(0.8f,500f);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Aufgabe3undFolgende().start("CG Aufgabe 3", 700, 700);
}
private int matrixID;
private int secondMatrixID;

private int snake;
private int greenSnake;

private GLFWKeyCallback input;

//cube normals
float[] normals = {..};
        //cube vertices
       float[] cube = {..};

       //pyramid vertices

      float[] pyramid = {..};
      //uv coordinates for pyramid
      float[] uv = {..};
      //uv coordinates for cube
      float[] uvCoords = {..};



     @Override
    protected void init() {

    glfwSetKeyCallback(super.returnWindow(), input = new 
     MouseAndKeyboardControl());

    shaderProgram = new ShaderProgram("aufgabe3");

    //cube
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram.getId());
    matrixID = glGenVertexArrays();
    glBindVertexArray(matrixID);
    System.out.println(matrixID);

    //pass data in the buffer
    VBO(0, 3,cube);
    VBO(1, 3, normals);
    VBO( 2, 2, uvCoords);
    Texture texture = new Texture("snake.jpg", 8);
    snake = texture.getId();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, snake);


    //pyramid
    shaderProgram2 = new ShaderProgram("render_pyramid");
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram2.getId());
    secondMatrixID = glGenVertexArrays();
    glBindVertexArray(secondMatrixID);
    System.out.println(secondMatrixID);

    //pass data in the buffer
    VBO(0, 3, pyramid);
    VBO(1, 2,uv);
    Texture texture2 = new Texture("greensnake.jpg", 8);
    greenSnake = texture2.getId();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, greenSnake);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // z-Buffer aktivieren
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); // backface culling aktivieren

    int loc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram.getId(), 
    "projectionMatrix");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, false,projection.getValuesAsArray());
     }



public void VBO(int index, int size, float[] name) {
    int vbold = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbold);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, name, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(index,size, GL_FLOAT, false, 0,0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(index);       
}

    @Override
    public void update() {
    matrix = new Matrix4();
    matrix.translate(2, 2, -4);
    secondMatrix = new Matrix4();
    secondMatrix.translate(-2, -1, -4);


    if (MouseAndKeyboardControl.keyPressed(49)) {
        secondMatrix.rotateX(0.3f);
    }
    if (MouseAndKeyboardControl.keyPressed(50)) {
        matrix.rotateY(0.3f);
    }

    }



    @Override
     protected void render() {
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);





      int loc1 = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram.getId(), "viewMatrix");
      glUniformMatrix4fv(loc1, false, matrix.getValuesAsArray());
      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, snake);
      glBindVertexArray(matrixID);
      glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);



    int loc2 = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram2.getId(), "viewMatrix2");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(loc2, false, secondMatrix.getValuesAsArray());
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, greenSnake);
    glBindVertexArray(secondMatrixID);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12);
    }

   @Override
   public void destroy() {
    }
```

I have tried to connect the shaders with the program in the *init()* Method. The name of the first shader is *aufgabe3* and the name of the second shader is *render_pyramid*. I appreciate any help you can provide!

Comment: You should use `glUseProgram(prg0); /* program 0 render code*/ glUseProgram(prg1); /* program 1 render code*/  /*stop rendering*/ glUseProgram(0);`You are trying to use 2 programs at time, which is not allowed by OpenGL and generally have no sense, if you have some tesselation stage add your tesselation shades into your single ShaderProgram object. 2. Check this [resource](https://learnopengl.com/)

Comment: Also you have an error in your renderer since you are using multi texturing, add  `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); glBindTexture(...)... glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1); glBindTexture(..)...`

Comment: @VictorGubin hey thanks a lot for your answer! I read the source and your comment and I think that this is what I am doing in the init() method. I call first glUseProgram(program0.id) then code to render and then glUseProgram(program1.id)and then code to render. Is this not how it should be?

Comment: Your `init` method doesn't actually render anything though.  All it's doing is setting various parts of the state of the current OpenGL context -- VBOs, shaders etc.  The actual rendering is done when you call `glDrawArrays`.  That's when the current shader will be used and, as your code stands, that will be `shaderProgram2`.